# EM Simulation with Advanced Design System from Agilent

Tags: simulation

Is there a clear simple tutorial out there regarding how to set up a via in designing a square-shape coil in ADS 2008? I'm actually trying to do a simulation using a T-Line Microstrip with two turns. Then adding two ports. In my Substrate, I have already defined two layers for the strips and in between these two layers, a layer for via. Id appreciate any thoughts, feedback, or ideas.

Comment: I think this question will end up being off topic for EE.SE (depending what kind of answers you get), but you can look here: http://wireless.agilent.com/vcentral/listvideos.aspx?sv=&ind=%25&tech=%25&pa=EDA&sort=1&class=%25

Comment: @The Photon: This is a RF question. On topic.

Comment: @BrianCarlton, if the answers given just cover the first question ("Is there a ... tutorial out there...?"), it'll just be a web link. Maybe not off topic, but "not constructive" according to SE terminology.

Comment: Thanks all. So when i create my Schematic from Layout in ADS 2008 and then run the simulation i get this error message saying: 
Simulation / Synthesis Messages


Error detected by hpeesofsim during netlist parsing.
    ADS-syntax parser error in '<string/GEMX netlist>', line 19:
        `syntax error'

Status / Summary


hpeesofsim (*) 332.400 Sep 18 2008 (built: 09/18/08 17:16:08)
Copyright Agilent Technologies, 1989-2008.
--------------------
Simulation terminated due to error.
--------------------

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking through the examples directory and finding an example that's close to what you want to simulate, and then carefully modifying the example until you have the exact system you're trying to simulate.